# How to use IdentityDbContext instead of DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I am following a tutorial on how to build a MVC project. I am a beginner so i am following exact steps as in tutorial.
So far, my ApplicationDbContext inherited from DbContext and it was working fine.
Now i want that my ApllicationDbContext inherits IdentityDbContext instead of DbContext, but i get the following errors
[Errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShX4T.png).
I installed required NuGet packages (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI)

This is my ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RockyWebsite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RockyWebsite.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet <Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationType> ApplicationType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also my Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using RockyWebsite.Data;

namespace RockyWebsite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser>()
               
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSession(Options=> {

                Options.IdleTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                Options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                Options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentity` and `dotnet ef database update` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you installed 2 packages of entity framework;

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

---

Since you are using .NET CORE, you should remove and uninstall; `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`

Comment: And optionally install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` if you didn't already

Comment: Exceptionally helpful on both the answer here and the comment above. So hard to differentiate between naming conventions for EF Core and EF.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code in your context

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>{

   //Your DbSets

}
```

istead of

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext {

 //Your DbSets   

}
```

and write below method in your context :

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);                   
    }
```